# Are there connections between the woman fleeing the Dragon in Revelation 12 and the Great Whore in Revelation 17?

Tags: revelation

Are there any connections between the woman fleeing the Dragon in Revelation 12 and the Great Whore on the Dragon in Revelation 17?

Comment: Indeed there are. They are both mentioned in the bible. They are both female. Did you have anything else in mind ? Your question is not clear and I suggest you edit it to mark out the texts you are referring to (and quote them, to assist your readers) and that you explain more about what connection you, yourself, are seeing. Welcome to BH.

Comment: Flagged as RA, this is definitely trolling

Answer (score 2):

This is a fascinating question that becomes more interesting when placed in a larger context.  The book of Revelation has numerous contrasts or "counterpoints".  Here are a few:

- Mt Zion (ch 14) vs Armageddon (actually "Harmageddon = Mount of Meggido)
- Marriage of Lamb to Bride vs Prostitute and Kings of earth adultery
- Seal of God vs Mark of the Beast
- Harvest of Grain (righteous) Gathering of Grapes (wicked)
- New Jerusalem vs Babylon the Great City

There are many more.

The righteous woman of Ch 12 vs the harlot of ch 17 is yet another of these counterpoints or literary contrasts.  Here are more connections:

- The righteous woman gives birth the a male child; vs, the harlot gives birth the harlot daughters
- The righteous woman is clothed in the sun; vs, the harlot who is clothed in scarlet and purple
- The righteous woman is pursued by the great red dragon with seven heads and ten horns; vs, the harlot who rides a great red beast with seven heads and ten horns
- Both are (in different ways) associated with the blood of persecuted saints
- The righteous woman is attacked by a river/flood from the dragon; vs, the harlot who sits on many waters

etc.  The overall message here is one of extreme contrast between these two women and what they represent.